# Find if variable is set in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Can anyone point me to right direction? Im really confused (im a beginner :D).
Example:

```
<form action="<?php $_server['php_self'] ?>" method=post>
<table width="50%" style="border: 1px solid #999;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="35%">
        <input type="button" value="Add Subitem">
        <input type="button" value="Add Category">
    </td>
    <td width="65%">
        <input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="1">
        <input type="text" name="categ[]" value="Sample Category" >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add Subitem">
        <input type="button" value="Add Category">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="2">
        <input type="text" name="sub[]" value="Sample Subitem" >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add Subitem">
        <input type="button" value="Add Category">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="3">
        <input type="text" name="categ[]" value="Sample Category" >
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="insBut" value="Save">
</form>
```

how can i iterate in row[]? and find if that row has categ or sub? i tried this

```
$row = $_post['row'];
$categ = $_post['categ'];
$sub = $_post['sub'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($row);$ii){
    if (isset($categ[$i])){
        $insQuery = pg_query("insert into rptdata_categ (blah blah) values (blah blah)");
    }elseif (isset($sub[$i])) {
        $insQuery = pg_query("insert into rptdata_sub (blah blah) values (blah blah)");
    }
}
```

but the values are wrong, i tried to echo it with

```
echo $row[$i]."=".$categ[$i];
```

and it gives

```
1=Sample Category
2=Sample Category
3=
```

i know its just right if you think about it, but how can i make it like

```
1=Sample Category
2=
3=Sample Category
```

oh and before i forget the user can add category or subitem on their own with button Add Category or Subitem.

Comment: Does `$ii` read `$i++` in you actual code? Cos if not, this probably your problem (if it even parses)

Comment: So you retyped it instead of copy/pasting it? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the desired row number (in `row[]`), why not just put that in the `name` of the text input, and drop the hidden one entirely?

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="categ[1]" value="Sample Category" />
</td>
...
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sub[8]" value="Sample Subitem" />
</td>
```

And so on. Then the array indices of your choosing are populated already.

Comment: i dunno how many fields there are, it was just an example, user can insert a row anywhere and it can be categ or sub... like if u click "Add categ" on the second row, a row will be created between 1st and 2nd row so basically when a user click on a button a row will be created on top of the one the user clicked. . .

Answer (score 0):

Any empty array field won't count on the final array. You should just add the row number to those fields, like `sub[1]`, `sub[2]`.. you know how many fields there are on the first place, so you can add the new fields (JS right?) with the right row-ID to it, like set the number of the base fields (3) as start point, and each time the user clicks on the button you advancing the var